# Azure DevOps deployment groups agents installation with error message

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to create a release pipeline to copy my .jar file to the target machine (Windows VM).
I follow the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=net#create-a-deployment-group) and install agents on the VMs

[image]

It works fine on most VMs, however, some VMs setting up agents with error (but the installation seems to be successful, I can find the machines on Azure DevOps). Here is the log:
https://gist.github.com/frankShih/9eecd83e9fa82acc4a8436c01bdd16e9

Before the agent installation, it shows a warning that net framework version should be higher than 4.5 (currently 4.0)
[image]

And here is the error message in the release pipeline:
[image]

I have checked that all the user accounts shown on Azure DevOps deployment group are admin permission in each VM.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in prior

[Update1]
I set the path like this
[image]

I login the VM with same account, and I can see that path.
[image]

I also try to downgrade "copy file to target machine" to version "1.*", still no luck
[image]

[update2]
Add a new folder

[image]

Chagen "copy task" back to version 2.*

[image]

Pipeline error message still the same

[image]

And yeah, I cannot ping target Windows VM from azure pipeline agent (I use deault agent with free-tier)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the task from “Windows machine file copy” to “Copy files”. Problem solved.

Try not to copy files from the pipeline agent to the target machine, just copy files on the target machine directly.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

The task error is not related to the agent, the agent is configured and started to run.

You are using UNC path for the `Destination Folder`, please login the agent machine with the user which is same in your task, check if the UNC path can be accessed.
[image]
[image]

If not, please check if you have shared the Drive on the target machine, and make sure the account has write permission.

[image]

It's working fine on my side with UNC path:

[image]

It's recommended to use a local path(eg: `cL\testcopy`) for the Destination folder for a test firstly, it will make sure the account&Password, IP/FQDN are fine and the account has enough permission to work on target machine.

Comment: Please check my update, thanks

Comment: 1.Please try to create a folder under D drive on target VM with the account, make sure you are able to. 
2. Use version2 task.
3. Please provide the pipline error message
4. Try to ping the target VM on the Deployment group agent, make sure it's successful.

Comment: Hi, it seems that I find the root cause: network issue (please check the update). However, I am not sure how to fix it ...

Comment: If you are using Deployment group agent, it should be local machine not free tier (Microsoft Hosted agent).  Could you please double check the agent used?
If your target VM is not exposed to public, the Microsoft hosted agent cannot find your target VM. To access your local target VM, you need to set up a deployment group agent and use it for your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

That's access related error. Check which account is your agent using, in deployment groups.

Can either reconfigure that account to be system account with all the privileges or give that account (used by agent) read and write privileges in that folder you making the copy.

Comment: What is "reconfigure" mean? Re-install agent? How to do that?
Tha account shown in Azure DevOps is the admin account in my VM.